# apache redirection is adding query string to the new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

apache mod rewrite is acting weird on me:
im trying to redirect this:
`http://www.website.com/page.php?id=34`
to this:
`http://www.website.com/`

using this in the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ "http://www.website.com" [R=301,L]
```

it works fine, but it also adds the query string to the redirected url:

`http://www.website.com/?id=34`

how do I remove the query string from the redirected url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, mod_rewrite won't change the query strings, it'll keep them unchanged and pass them to whatever the new URI is. To remove them, you need to end the new URL with a question mark. You also don't need the quotation marks around it. This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://www.website.com? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if it is going to work but try:

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php "http://www.website.com" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but it still adds the query string to the new url